# Working with HTTPS request and async functions to database using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create my second Firebase Function using the real-time Database. The idea is to receive a HTTPS request, then the function fetches data on a node called **buffer**, it processes all that data, pushes it into a node called **history** and then removes the data processed from the buffer. I think I am doing something wrong with `promises`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
export const processBuffer = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {

    const refBuffer = admin.database().ref('/buffer')
    refBuffer.on('value', ( dataSnapShot ) => {

        const promises = []
        const snapshot = dataSnapShot.val()

        for( const id in snapshot ) {

            // Processs data in the buffer

            let keys = []

            ...

            let promise = admin.database().ref('/history').child(id).push().set({ timestamp: timestamp, value: value } )
            .then( (e) => {

                keys.forEach( key => {
                    let p  = admin.database().ref('/buffer').child(id).child(key).remove()
                    promises.push(p)
                })

                return Promise.all(promises)
            })
        }

        response.send("Ok")
    })
})
```

It works as expected if I don't remove the nodes from buffer. But if I do, for whatever reason, it messes up my history node. For example, if I have 3 elements in the buffer, there should be 3 elements in history after it is processed. This works when I don't remove the elements from the buffer, but when I try to remove those nodes, they get multiplied in history by an increment of 1 (first node gets one element, second node gets two element, third gets three...)

Does anyone know where I am messing this up?

Comment: Instead of using the `on()` method, and have the callback triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data changes, you should use the `once()` method, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#once

Comment: Ok. But what if my data is time-depedent? It should be processed at the end of every hour.

Comment: To process it at the end of each hour, you should use an external service like https://cron-job.org/en/ to call the HTTPS Cloud Function

Comment: Yep, that's what I am trying to do. I just implemented your suggestions from your answer, thank you, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Please do not rollback the edits any further, CodingCaio. That you're new to typescript isn't relevant to the question

Comment: Sure, since you asked nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several areas in your code where there might be problems:

1/ Instead of using the `on()` method, and have the callback triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data changes, you should use the `once()` method, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#once

2/ The `Promise.all()` call shall be outside of the `for( const id in snapshot )` loop: the idea is to populate the `promises` array and after it is entirely populated, call `Promise.all()`

3/ You should not call `admin.database().ref('/history').child(id).push().set()` several times in the loop. Use the `update()` method (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#update)) that allows "writing multiple values to the Database at once."

4/ You should also wait that `Promise.all(promises)` resolves before returning the response, as follows:

```
   ....
   for( const id in snapshot ) {
      //populate the promises array
   }

   return Promise.all(promises)
})
.then((result) => {
   response.send("Ok")
})
.catch(...)
```